# How to force a user to re-enter login password using PAPE extension with max_auth_age=0

Tags: google-app-engine, openid

I am using OpenID with GAE (Experimental - Federated Login). I don't
get prompted for user/password when I hit logout and then hit login
back again. Can someone please let me know what the problem is?

I use the following code to create my login url's:

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
HashSet<String> attributeRequestSet = new HashSet<String>();
attributeRequestSet.add("openid.ns.pape=http://specs.openid.net/
extensions/pape/1.0");
attributeRequestSet.add("openid.pape.max_auth_age=0");
String loginUrl = userService.createLoginURL(destinationUrl,
"gmail.com", "gmail.com", attributeRequestSet);
```

and code for my logout url's:

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
String logoutUrl = userService.createLogoutURL(destinationUrl,
user.getAuthDomain())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are logged in to your Google account it will not request you to input username/password.

If you logout of your app and then login again, you are redirected to Google auth page, but since you are still logged into Google it just immediately redirects you back to your app.

The OpenID feature you are requesting `(openid.pape.max_auth_age=0)` is not yet supported: see [Unsupported Features](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html#uf)

Comment: So how do you think should I go to get my behavior: A person who has logged out of my app should have to login back by passing user/password. Presently, I have a workaround -- After someone hits logout I show a logout successful page and on this page I ask the user to logout of the Google account as well.

Comment: They are not presenting user/pass to your site, but to Google. This is the point of OpenID. But since they did not log out of google, they do not need to enter user/pass again. StackOverflow it behaving the same way. When you logout you only logout of SO, not Google. When you log back io you are not presented with user/pass.